# Find the highest value key in an object, then post it to an innerHTML

Tags: javascript, loops, object

I have an object that i'm tallying quiz question results in.

```
var answerData = {
    "Ninja": { score: 4 },
    "Robot": { score: 1 },
    "Pirate": { score: 7 },
    "Zombie": { score: 2 }
}
```

I'd like to determine which attribute is the highest then post the results to the page.

I found a post here on stackoverflow that suggested using object.reduce() to get a final result. I can't get it to return the highest value of 'pirate', instead it returns the last value of 'zombie'.

```
  function finalResults {
        theAnswer = Object.keys(answerData).reduce(function(a, b){ return answerData[a] > answerData[b] ? a : b });

        document.getElementById("finalResulthere").innerHTML = "<p>Congratulations you are a " + theAnswer +".</p>";
}
```

To then post it to

```
<div id="results">
  <div id="finalResulthere"></div>
</div>
```

My alternative thoughts were to run chained IF statements comparing the values of each of the object keys. This appeared to be neater...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You function is almost complete, you just miss a detail, you are comparing the complete object and it always fail.

```
function finalResults() {
    var theAnswer = Object.keys(answerData).
                reduce(function(a, b){ 
                   return answerData[a].score > answerData[b].score ? a : b }
                );

    document.getElementById("finalResulthere").innerHTML = "<p>Congratulations you are a " + theAnswer +".</p>";
}
```

you need to compare using the value of the `score` property, that is what you are missing

Comment: That makes complete sense. Thank you!